# Product Line Run

Tags: word-meaning

I need some help with the meaning of "run" in:

> [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers%3a_Generation_1)
>   Transformers: Generation 1 (also known as Generation One or G1) was a children's toy line that ***ran*** from 1984 to 1991 and was produced by Hasbro.

I cannot find a good definition for "*run*" that would fit this sentence.  Could the sentence be an error?

Answer (score 1):

[***run***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/run) :

> 14 a. A continuous period of operation, especially of a machine or factory.
>    b. The production achieved during such a period: a press run of 15,000 copies.

The applicable verb is:

> [***run***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/run) : 8. To be in operation: *The engine is running.*

Comment: You definition for the noun "run".  My sentence uses the verb "run".

Comment: Yes, the toy production line *ran*, as in a continuous period of operation, especially of a machine or factory, between the years of 1984 to 1991.

Comment: I would go with (v.intr) sense 26, "To be presented or performed for a continuous period of time: *The play ran for six months*."

Comment: There is a difference between a product line and a production line:  The former is a group of products.  The latter is similar to an assembly line.  A toy line is definitely a produce line.

Comment: @user3169- Yes, that also works. Often you will find that multiple senses of a word fit a given situation.

Comment: @meatie- You are right than a product line is a set of related products and a production line implements a manufacturing process to produce such products. But here we are kind mixing the two because to have the product line *run* from 1984 to 1991 means that it was in production during those years- the use of *run* is a reference to the machines that needed to be *running* in order to produce the products.

Comment: So, this is technical jargon?